# Scheduling notifications

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, push-notification

So I got a little problem here.
My App needs to fire notifications everyday at the same time.
It does this now by the code that's inside the application.

However, I want to schedule these notifications on my server and then schedule them on the device until it's time to go off.
I've read about Push notifications and also that they are unreliable as an alarm so I guess that's not a good idea.

So my question is, is it possible to make the App read the times from a server and then schedule them locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just use `UILocalNotification`. You don't need to involve push notifications.

Comment: Yes, I'm doing this now. The problem is that I want those UILocalnotifications loaded from a server first. So for example Server has a file with 3 times 08.00/08.15/08.30 --> Device checks this file --> Device Schedules the notifications. The reason why is that whenever a time changes, I need to update my App everytime. So my question is, is this possible?

Comment: Not unless you make sure your app is running and can keep re-scheduling those local notifications. (You can schedule them far in advance, though.) The only alternative is to use push notifications.

Comment: Okay thanks, So this can't be done unless I use push notifications, thanks anyway just wanted to make sure if it was possible or not :)

Comment: There is a trade-off here, using `UILocalNotification` guarantees you the scheduled notification will go off on time but Push does not provide you that stability. But you will only be able to get the latest notification times from the server each time your app is loaded while using `UILocalNotification` - where Push does not require that. As I said, it's a matter of choice between these trade-off's :)

Comment: Yep understand that, the times just need to be static and exact so I will stick to the localnotifications and submit update's to Apple if needed, thanks!